# Limit and continuity of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Test the continuity at the origin of the following function:
> $$
> f(z)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2} &\text{for $z\neq0$,}\\
> 0 &\text{for $z=0$.}\\
> \end{cases}$$

z can tend to zero along $y$ or $x$-axis. But, in  both the cases, it is $0$. I tried along the curve $y=mx$, but there is an extra term $x^2$. I can't understand along which path the discontinuity of the function can be proved. Please help.

Comment: For $y=x$, we have $f=1$.

Comment: Did you actually mean to test the function's continuity at the origin or its discontinuity there ? I am a teen and hasn't completely understood your doubt. Plus, I haven't studied this before and am trying to use what I have to solve this.

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham Yes the question is to test the continuity and in my book it is given that the function is discontinuous. Btw I am also a teen:)

Comment: Well, I am 15 now.

Comment: Yeah... not the right person to answer you, I suppose...

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham 

Comment: Wow ! My first 'international' debut as a joker ! Thank God !

Comment: By the by, I think that, had you avoided the conditional part and simply defined the function as an algebraic expression in $x$ and $y$, the function could be discontinuous at $x = y = 0$.